# How to hide command prompt window when using Exec in Golang?

Tags: windows, go, command-line, system-calls

say i have the following code, using `syscall` to hide command line window

```golang
process := exec.Command(name, args...)
process.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true}
err := process.Start()
if err != nil {
    log.Print(err)
}
```

but when i compiled it and tried to run it in Windows, command line window showed up again

what can i do to prevent command line window from appearing?

PS i already know how to compile golang source into a Windows GUI executable using `go build -ldflags -H=windowsgui`, but doing so only ensures the program itself doesn't bring up a command line window, `Exec` will show those windows anyway

Comment: Can you please be more precise about which prompt you are trying to hide?
You already stated the correct commands hide both, the Go command line window and the windows spawned by exec. My best guess at the moment is that the command you are executing spawns an additional window.

Comment: It's possible too, I am going to check which command spawns the command prompt (disappears very soon though)

Comment: @jm33_m0 I have just tried, the sysProcAttr method in your question and it is a vast improvement -windows only flash briefly. Did you ever find a solution to prevent the flash completely

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[There](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/2c1g3x/build_golang_app_reverse_shell_to_run_in_windows/) is a better solution, which can run `exec.Command()` without spawn a visible window, ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°).

Here is my code:

Firstly `import "syscall"`

```
cmd_path := "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"
cmd_instance := exec.Command(cmd_path, "/c", "notepad")
cmd_instance.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true}
cmd_output, err := cmd_instance.Output()
```

Origin: 
https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/2c1g3x/build_golang_app_reverse_shell_to_run_in_windows/

Comment: This actually answers the question. Thanks!

Comment: It is probably safer to use `os.Getenv("windir")` for the directory though.

Comment: @KarelBílek Yeah, but I haven't seen that a cmd in  windows system doesn't locate in that place :) .

Comment: I'm not sure how should I thank you. Since yesterday I've tried at least 50 ways of hiding this terminal window. I was frustrated with the terminal window and I was starting to hate black color in real life. Thanks again. You are a saviour.

Comment: Don't forget to add the flag when build `go build -ldflags="-H windowsgui" main.go`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of hiding the console window, you should be able to prevent it with:

```
cmd := exec.Command(...)
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{CreationFlags: 0x08000000} // CREATE_NO_WINDOW
```

Comment: This seems to work in Windows, but in WSL ubuntu, when I compiled (with an older version of golang), I got `csrc/sclaunch.go:759:42: unknown field 'CreationFlags' in struct literal of type syscall.SysProcAttr`

Comment: CreationFlags is only for Windows, not Linux

Answer (score 5):

If you build with `-ldflags -H=windowsgui`, each exec.Command will spawn a new console window.

If you build without the flag, you get **one** console window and all exec.Commands print into that one.

My current solution is thus to build **without** the flag, i.e. have a console window on program start, then immediately hide the console window with this code at the start of my program:

```
import "github.com/gonutz/w32/v2"

func hideConsole() {
    console := w32.GetConsoleWindow()
    if console == 0 {
        return // no console attached
    }
    // If this application is the process that created the console window, then
    // this program was not compiled with the -H=windowsgui flag and on start-up
    // it created a console along with the main application window. In this case
    // hide the console window.
    // See
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009333/how-to-check-if-the-program-is-run-from-a-console
    _, consoleProcID := w32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(console)
    if w32.GetCurrentProcessId() == consoleProcID {
        w32.ShowWindowAsync(console, w32.SW_HIDE)
    }
}
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9009783/6276385) for the details about the process ID stuff.

What happens is that all exec.Commands now print their output to the hidden console window instead of spawning their own.

The compromise here is that your program will flash a console window once when you start it, but only for a brief moment before it goes into hiding.

Comment: I had only seen an issue on win 7, not 8 but I just retested this on a windows 7 machine and it does indeed work there as described - I'm not sure why I got an error when i tried previously - comment removed to avoid confusion. answer upvoted as I will now be using this approach

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/494000/278842