Supress "terminal-window" when executing an elevated windows command
An GUI application I wrote executes elevated diskpart /s some_script.  This works fine except for the fact that a terminal window is popping open showing the execution of diskpart.  I wonder if there is a way to suppress the display of that terminal window.
How to hide command prompt window when using Exec in
Golang? suggests three ways to deal with the problem:

hide the command window
prevent the command window
hide the app's command window

The following code implements all three suggestions none of which works on my windows 10 pro machine (i.e. the terminal window pops up in each case).
Any other idea how to solve this or did I got something wrong?
Note: to test 1. and 2. go build -ldflags -H=windowsgui should be used to build following code and for 3. go build only.  In the last case the build exe must not be executed from a command line.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "syscall"

    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/layout"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
    "github.com/getlantern/elevate"
    "github.com/gonutz/w32/v2"
)

func init() { log.Default().SetFlags(0) }

// see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42500570/how-to-hide-command-prompt-window-when-using-exec-in-golang
func main() {
    a := app.New()
    win := a.NewWindow("hide window")
    hideCmd := widget.NewButton("hide command window", hideCmdWindow)
    preventCreation := widget.NewButton("prevent command window", preventCmdWindow)
    hideApp := widget.NewButton("hide app command window", hideAppCmdWindow)
    grid := container.New(layout.NewGridLayout(1), hideCmd, preventCreation, hideApp)
    win.SetContent(grid)
    win.ShowAndRun()
}

func hideCmdWindow() {
    scriptFile := writeScript()
    defer os.RemoveAll(filepath.Dir(scriptFile))
    cmd_path := "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"
    cmd := elevate.Command(cmd_path, "/c", "diskpart", "/s", scriptFile)
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{HideWindow: true}
    bb, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("can't execute diskpart with script: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bb))
}

func preventCmdWindow() {
    scriptFile := writeScript()
    defer os.RemoveAll(filepath.Dir(scriptFile))
    cmd := elevate.Command("diskpart", "/s", scriptFile)
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{CreationFlags: 0x08000000}
    bb, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("can't execute diskpart with script: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bb))
}

const (
    noWinGuiFlag        = "build without -ldflags=\"-H windowsgui\""
    executedFromConsole = "don't execute the program from a command line"
)

func hideAppCmdWindow() {
    console := w32.GetConsoleWindow()
    // probably CRASHES here if build with -H flag
    if console == 0 {
        fmt.Println("no console attached:", noWinGuiFlag)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009333/how-to-check-if-the-program-is-run-from-a-console
    _, consoleProcID := w32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(console)
    if w32.GetCurrentProcessId() == consoleProcID {
        w32.ShowWindowAsync(console, w32.SW_HIDE)
    }
    if w32.GetCurrentProcessId() != consoleProcID {
        fmt.Println("app-id != console-id:", executedFromConsole)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    scriptFile := writeScript()
    defer os.RemoveAll(filepath.Dir(scriptFile))
    cmd := elevate.Command("diskpart", "/s", scriptFile)
    bb, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("can't execute diskpart with script: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(bb))
}

const (
    scriptName     = "list_disks"
    diskpartScript = "list\n"
)

// writeScript creates a simple diskpart script and stores it in a
// temporary directory.  The full filename of that script is returned.
func writeScript() string {
    wd, err := os.MkdirTemp("", "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("can't create working directory: %v", err)
    }

    scriptFile := filepath.Join(wd, scriptName)
    err = os.WriteFile(scriptFile, []byte(diskpartScript), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("can't write diskpart-script: %v", err)
    }
    return scriptFile
}


You appear to us github.com/getlantern/elevate, not plain os/exec stuff. A cursory glance at elevate shows that on Windows, it even uses an embedded precompiled binary to do some magic. I'd bet the chief reason for SysProcAttr.CreationFlags not working for you is some strange interplay between all this stuff.

BTW reading the source code of that embedded tool reveals that it does its magic by virtue of calling shell32!ShellExecuteEx, which, IMO, kind of supports my suggestion. Given that the program I'm referring to does what you need, I'd just look at its source code and try to recreate its "no ComSpec" code path. (Well, and surfing for possible solutions brough this very interesting piece of code which appears to be able to actually pop up an UAC admin rights approval dialog, when needed.)

Oh, and hat I forgot to highlight is that the parameter structute to pass to the call to shell32!ShellExecuteEx has a field which controls showing of the window of a process to be created.

…continuing my train of thought, there's no way to redirect the standard I/O streams of a process started by ShellExecuteEx, so you won't be able to gather the output diskpart without resorting to calling it via shell (say, cmd.exe) and using shell's redirection to temporary files, which you have to read afterwards. To me, it looks like a better path forward would be exploring how to obtain a token with elevated creds to pass to os/exec.Cmd via SysProcAttr.Token.

@kostix thank you very much for your valuable thoughts! I'll investigate when I find the time.

As suggested by kostix adapting elevating by process token (windows.OpenProcessToken) and using the the show-flag of windows.ShellExecute solved the problem.
