# How windows executable knows whether it is opened from console

Tags: windows, powershell, console

Recently I have installed git-lfs (from https://git-lfs.github.com/) for Windows. Accidentally I tried to run the executable 'git-lfs.exe' outside the console by double clicking on it; the following message appears:

[image]

This prompt awoke my curiosity. Usually, there is no distinction between running executable from command line or from Windows Explorer. **How can windows executable know if it has been executed from console or not?** Imagine we want to write a program which detects if a program was ran from console or not. Can this be written platform independent, or it requires the usage of platform dependent API (as stated in [How to check if the program is run from a console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009333/how-to-check-if-the-program-is-run-from-a-console))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's find out! It's an open source project, so the code is all there for exploring (pun intended).

First off, clone the repository for easier searching: `git clone https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs.git`. One can search via Github too, but a local copy is easier to work with.

Then, use a tool such as `grep` to find a piece of the error message:

```
grep -r "command line tool" *
vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra.go:var MousetrapHelpText string = `This is a command line tool.
vendor/github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap/README.md:Windows developers unfamiliar with command line tools will often "double-click"
```

Looks like there is a string that contains the message. What's the Mousetrap thing and where is it used?

```
grep -r "MousetrapHelpText" *
vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra.go:// MousetrapHelpText enables an information splash screen on Windows
vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra.go:var MousetrapHelpText string = `This is a command line tool.
vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command_win.go:   if MousetrapHelpText != "" && mousetrap.StartedByExplorer() {
vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command_win.go:       c.Print(MousetrapHelpText)
```

Looks interesting. Let's go to `https://github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap` for the source. There's the `command_win.go` file that contains the magic.

TL;DR: A Windows process has startup info that contains parent process id. If that's the same Explorer.exe (Win GUI shell), assume GUI launching.